# How to fetch the message string from Win32 provided HRESULT C#

Tags: c#, hresult

I'm curious if there is a function in `C#` to convert an Win32 `HRESULT (long)` error code gotten from unmanaged code into the representation `string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m not aware of a single function but the workaround is easy enough.

```
public static string formatMessage( int hr ) =>
    Marshal.GetExceptionForHR( hr ).Message;
```

**Update:** the “duplicate” question is very different.

HRESULT codes are documented in [section 2.1 of the [MS-ERREF] spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/0642cb2f-2075-4469-918c-4441e69c548a).

Any Win32 code can be packed into HRESULT, by using Severity=1 and Facility=FACILITY_WIN32. The opposite is not true, FACILITY_WIN32 is just one of the many. The accepted answer to the “duplicate” question, which uses `Win32Exception`, doesn’t apply to this question.

Here's a quick demo.

```
static void testHresultMessages()
{
    int hr = new OverflowException().HResult;

    // Prints "Unknown error (0x80131516)"
    Console.WriteLine( new Win32Exception( hr ).Message );

    // Prints "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow."
    Console.WriteLine( Marshal.GetExceptionForHR( hr ).Message );
}
```